# Не правильно выполняются тесты

Tags: java, очередь

Не могу понять в чем ошибка при выполнении тестов. Либо метод tostring или remove некорректны.

```java
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class QueueImpl implements Queue {

    private SListNode head;
    private SListNode tail;
    private int size;

    public QueueImpl() {
        size = 0;
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    private static class SListNode {
        public Object item;
        public SListNode next;

        SListNode(Object obj) {
            item = obj;
            next = null;
        }

        SListNode(Object obj, SListNode next) {
            item = obj;
            this.next = next;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void enqueue(Object element) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new SListNode(element);
            tail = head;
        } else {
            tail.next = new SListNode(element);
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        size++;
    }


    @Override
    public Object dequeue() {
        if (head == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        } else {
            Object o = head.item;
            head = head.next;
            size--;
            if (size == 0) {
                tail = null;
            }
            return o;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object top() {
        if (head == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        } else {
            return head.item;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        size = 0;
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
        return new IteratorImpl();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (size == 0) {
            return "[]";
        } else {
            IteratorImpl iterator = new IteratorImpl();
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("[");
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                SListNode currentNode = (SListNode) iterator.next();
                result.append(currentNode.item.toString());
                if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    result.append(", ");
                } else {
                    result.append("]");
                }
            }
            return result.toString();
        }
    }

    private class IteratorImpl implements Iterator<Object> {

        private int index = 0;
        private SListNode lastReturned;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < size;

        }

        public Object next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            index++;
            if (lastReturned == null) {
                lastReturned = head;
                return lastReturned;
            }
            lastReturned = lastReturned.next;
            return lastReturned;
        }

        public void remove() {
            if (index == 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            SListNode nxt = lastReturned.next;
            QueueImpl.this.top();
            lastReturned = nxt;
            index--;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test1();
        test2();
        test3();
        test4();
        test5();
        test6();
        test7();
        test8();
        test9();
        test10();
    }

    public static void test1() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        Class c = queue.getClass();
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        // must be 1
        System.out.println(c.getInterfaces().length);

        // must be Queue
        System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getSimpleName());

        // must be 1
        System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces().length);

        // must be Container
        System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces()[0].getSimpleName());

        // must be 1
        System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces().length);

        // must be java.lang.Iterable
        System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces()[0].getInterfaces()[0].getName());

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * 1 Queue 1 Container 1 java.lang.Iterable
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test2() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(queue);
        System.out.println(queue.size());

        queue.clear();
        System.out.println(queue);
        System.out.println(queue.size());

        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");

        System.out.println(queue);
        System.out.println(queue.size());

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * [A, B, C] 3 [] 0 [A, B, C] 3
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test3() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        System.out.print(queue.dequeue());
        System.out.print(queue.dequeue());
        System.out.print(queue.dequeue());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(queue);

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * ABC []
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test4() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        for (Object element : queue) {
            System.out.print(element);
        }

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * ABC
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test5() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        Iterator it = queue.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(it.next());
        }
        System.out.println();
        it = queue.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(it.next());
        }

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * ABC ABC
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test6() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        Iterator it = queue.iterator();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(queue);

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * A B C []
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test7() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        Iterator it = queue.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        System.out.println(it.next());
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(queue);

        it = queue.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(queue);

        it = queue.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(queue);

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * A B C [A, B] A [B] B []
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test8() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        Iterator it = queue.iterator();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        try {
            it.remove();
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            System.out.println("exception");
        }

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * A exception
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test9() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        Iterator it = queue.iterator();
        try {
            it.remove();
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            System.out.println("exception");
        }

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * exception
         *************************************
         */
    }

    public static void test10() {
        System.out.println("\n" + "--------------------------------------");
        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        System.out.println(queue.top());

        /*
         * an output must be as the following:
         *************************************
         * A
         *************************************
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Какой именно тест? какая ошибка?

Comment: @Z.John Начиная с 4 теста , ошибочно выводит "QueueImpl$SListNode@1cd072a9" вместо нужной информации.

Comment: @Z.John в 4 тесте хотел увидеть "ABC" а к сожалению увидел "QueueImpl$SListNode@1cd072a9".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в `IteratorImpl` метод `next()` возвращает `return lastReturned;`, где `lastReturned` - это узел `SListNode`

Соответственно итератор `for (Object element : queue)` в 4 тесте точно также получает объекты типа `SListNode`

вероятно метод `next()` должен возвращать:

`return (lastReturned == null) ? null : lastReturned.item`;

обращаю также внимание, что метод `next()` итератора при следующем вызове после последнего элемента не выкинет исключение а выполнит `lastReturned = lastReturned.next;` таким образом `lastReturned` будет равно `null`. Вероятно, это не то, что ожидается.